# time() to DateTime

Tags: php, date, datetime, twig

I have an application that uses `time()` to record the time a topic was posted. I have done this for a long time and the only glitch i ever had with the method was that the time was always off by an hour (mainly a DST issue i never looked into).

I'm want to switch to the `DateTime` method, since I'm also switching to Twig, which uses that date format when setting a timezone.

But from what I can see, you can't use timestamps to parse the date. my question is, how do you input a date and parse it and what format are they looking for if it isn't `time()`?

Comment: it followed until half of the second paragraph.. then it is not very clear..

Comment: I'm assuming this is database driven (given your mention of saving topic creation time) so my biggest question is--why aren't you using the DB's integrated time? (Let the database handle the time, PHP should only convert it to a local time for the user).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the sounds of it your server's default timezone is UTC. I suggest you try changing the `default_timezone` setting in `php.ini` to something that applies DST. This will mean that when you use `date()`, the resulting output will be correctly adjusted for DST.

Comment: the thing is, this application is used on different systems, so i sorta need to do something that the typical user can do on a shared hosting account. I wouldn't mind to UTC if i knew what i had to do to make the switch.

Comment: example of what I'm talking about: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html

Comment: `date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London")` would help you. Or whatever timezone you need. Just put that at the start of your PHP scripts and you don't have to worry.

Comment: the issue is, each user could be at a different timezone. also all my time values are in time, datetime doesnt accept it.

Answer (score 0):

> you can't use timestamps to parse the date

There is a way, if your php version is >=5.3 :

```
$time = time();//or other time
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('U',$time);
```

but as a matter of fact it is somewhat weird to use timestamp as DateTime does not rely on it. You can parse a date string directly with the datetime constructor if your date is english or "french" (i.e `d/m/y`). You can also create your custom format.

> how do you input a date and parse it and what format are they looking for if it isn't time()

if it is a a standard format date :

```
$date = new DateTime($yourString);//would throw an exception if the format is wrong
```

if it is a custom format, like DD/MM/YYYY 14h32mins

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h\hi\m\i\n\s',$yourString);
if($date === false){//if format does not fit
   exit('Your wrong !');
}
```

> I have an application that uses time() to record the time a topic was posted.

Very bad practice. In MySQL you have DateTime format (and each relational data base system has his own equivalent) to store date times and there are fully compatible with the DateTime constructor in PHP so migrate to it (use FROM_TIMESTAMP to change into DateTime).